# Loading ONNX model in c# for Microsoft HoloLens

Tags: windows, hololens, windows-machine-learning

I've a problem when load and evaluate ONNX model with Windows Machine Learning API. 
I try to load the model for evaluation with Microsoft HoloLens but when I evaluate the model the code generate some exceptions like: `"No suitable kernel definition found for op. Unsqueeze".`

Anyone has found the same problem when working with HoloLens?

Comment: Hi Lorenzo, may I ask what ai.onnx version is your model? Windows Machine Learning supports version 7 for Windows build 17763 and version 8 for our insider users with builds > 17763.